# Blocked by Spamhaus When Trying to Validate Email Using Python

Tags: python, smtp

I'm trying to check whether an email exists or not using Python's smtplib

This is what I did:

```
s = smtplib.SMTP()
s.connect(mxRecord) 
s.mail('my@email.com') //Here the error shows up
```

The error is:
Client host [**.**.**.**] blocked using Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso (S3130)

Comment: You'll need to get yourself off the blacklist (SpamHaus). However, I don't recommend doing this. Imagine a spammer who could check for "valid email addresses" -- this would be a very simple harvesting technique. It's probably what got your app flagged.

Comment: Getting myself off the blacklist requires having a non-free email (hotmail and gmail are not accepted). I guess it's for the same reason you mentioned here. I was wondering if there was another way I can communicate with SMTP to get the status code.

Comment: My guess is that you have an assumption upstream you need to revisit. There are more standard ways to validate an email address, that it was received, etc.

Comment: What if there were a thousand one that need to be validated :-/

Comment: There are services that track this kind of thing. Otherwise, be very careful as it's easy to run afoul of anti-scam/spam/hacker measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something and it worked well.

```
import dns.resolver, smtplib
MyEmail = "X@hotmail.com"
MyPassword = "XXX"
EmailToValidate = "X@Y.com"

record = dns.resolver.query(str.split(EmailToValidate, "@")[1], "MX")
mx = str(record[0].exchange)

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.live.com", 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(MyEmail, MyPassword)
server.helo("live.com")
server.connect(mx)
server.mail(MyEmail)

code, msg = server.rcpt(EmailToValidate)
print("Code: ", str(code), " message: ", msg)
```

the (code, message) pair will be (250, OK) if the email exists, and (550, Address Rejected) if the email does not exists.

I wrote this on hurry, so there might be some unnecessary steps.